# C# Enumerable yield and foreach

Tags: c#

The professor today asks us in the class to solve this exercise in C# can someone help me out i'm lost...

The purpose of this exercise and the next one is to emphasize the power of enumerables and the
yield and foreach statements.
Declare a generic static method Flatten that takes as argument an array of `IEnumerable<T>` and returns an
`IEnumerable<T>`. Use foreach statements and the yield return statement. The method should have this
header:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(IEnumerable<T>[] ebles) { ... }
```

If you call the method as shown below, you should get  2 3 5 7 2 3 5 7 2 3 5 7:

```
IEnumerable<int>[] ebles = new IEnumerable<int>[3];
ebles[0] = ebles[1] = ebles[2] = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
foreach (int i in Flatten<int>(ebles))
Console.Write(i + " ");
```

Comment: What specifically would you like help with?

Comment: Indeed - there's no actual *question* asked here...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: That compiles... why did you think it wouldn't? It's an array of sequences of integers...

Comment: What specific problem do you have? It is a rather simple assignment. Which point is hard for you to plan or implement?

Comment: <irony>return new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 7 }</irony>

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, it's an array of enumerables. My bad.

Comment: @DmitriTsoy, the *perfect* TDD answer! :)

Comment: Method body: `return ebles.SelectMany(i => i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two nested foreach loops. One iterates the `ebles` the inner one the elements in each list. The innermost loop contains a `yield return element`;

This is the outline. Now go and read about each of the words mentioned in this outline.